# Position of absolute element changes when innerHTML is changed

Tags: javascript, css

I have a button that is absolutely positioned within a div, when this button is clicked and the innerHTML changed (to simulate a play button), the position of the button moves. I believe this is a problem with the rotation transformation. How could I solve this so the button does not move? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
const playButton = document.querySelector('#play');
let paused = false;

playButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (paused == true) {
        playButton.innerHTML = "Pause";
        paused = false;
    } else {
        playButton.innerHTML = "Play";
        paused = true;
    }
});
```

```css
#outer {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
}
#play {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
<button id="play">Play</button>
</div>
```

Comment: set the width so it does not change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is to do with the width - as pause is longer than play, the transform origin will be different (it's default is to start in the centre).  To solve this, you could give the button a fixed width:

```js
const playButton = document.querySelector('#play');
let paused = false;

playButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (paused == true) {
    playButton.innerHTML = "Pause";
    paused = false;
  } else {
    playButton.innerHTML = "Play";
    paused = true;
  }
});
```

```css
#outer {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
}

#play {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 5em;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <button id="play">Play</button>
</div>
```

[More information about transform origin](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform-origin/)

Answer (score 2):

Adjust the origin of the transformation and also the transformation like below and your button will simply grow without moving:

```js
const playButton = document.querySelector('#play');
let paused = false;

playButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (paused == true) {
        playButton.innerHTML = "Pause";
        paused = false;
    } else {
        playButton.innerHTML = "Play";
        paused = true;
    }
});
```

```css
#outer {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
}
#play {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform-origin:left center;
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(100%) ;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
<button id="play">Play</button>
</div>
```